# What is causing this strange shuffle algorithm behavior?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So this sorting algorithm is something I pulled off of here and I'm just trying to wrap my head around how it works. When I put `alert(i)` in this position, it will alert all five times as expected.

```
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length; i; i--) {
        alert(i)
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
    }
}
```

But if I put it in this position it only alerts once.

```
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length; i; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        alert(i)
        [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
    }
}
```

What's causing this? Isn't the loop still running 5 times?

Comment: I thought it injects semicolons. What is it doing that makes it only call alert once?

Comment: The automatic semicolon assertion is somewhat broken feature, just always use semicolons. Hit F12 to see, what is breaking the code ...

Comment: I tryed your code (with semicolons). i get the same amount of alerts.
[IE --> hit F12] | [Chrome --> Ctrl+Shift+I] | [Firefox --> Ctrl+Shift+Q]

Comment: @Glufu F12 opens a devtool console in all major browsers, though the keyboard shortcuts you've introduced will work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that the omitted semicolon after your `alert` is causing the problem:

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length; i; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        alert(i)
        [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
    }
}
```

Line 4+5 are being parsed as:

```js
        alert(i)[a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
```

meaning the JS interpreter is trying to access the return value of the alert as an array (which it isn't, obviously). The error prevents your loop from continuing, so you only get the first alert.

I recommend reading [Ben Alman's blog post](http://benalman.com/news/2013/01/advice-javascript-semicolon-haters/) (satirical rant) for a bit more on semicolons in JavaScript.